# `this` is lost when I use lit-html expressions

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, es6-class, lit-element

I'm training with LitElement and lit-html. I'm trying to make complex templates with functions and event listener. I have a module for the template module
and another for one component where I use the templates.
I'm having problem with a template for a buttom which I pass a function as parameter and when I clicked on the buttom call the function.
This works: it makes the call but the reference for `this` is lost. I thought a possible cause maybe the arrow function so I rewrote the function like this:

```
let timerElementOperation = function(operationTimer, operation,that){
    operationTimer.bind(that);
    return html` <button @click=${function(){operationTimer()}}>${operation}</button> `;
}
```

But the problem is still there. What's happening?

```
//timer-element.js
class TimerElement extends LitElement{
    ...
    static get properties(){
        return {
            running:  { type: Boolean, reflect: true}
        };
    }
    render(){
        let partialTemplate;
        if( this.isPausable(this.running, this.finished) && this.time > 0 ){
            partialTemplate = Template.timerElementOperation(this.pause, 'pause');
        } else if(!this.running && this.time > 0){
            partialTemplate = Template.timerElementOperation(this.resume,'resume');
        }
    pause(){
        this.running = false; // this is lost.
    }

}

//timer-templates.js
import {html}   from '@polymer/lit-element';
let timerElementOperation = (operationTimer, operation) => {
    return html` <button @click=${()  => operationTimer()}>${operation}</button> `;
}

export timerElementOperation;
```

Comment: where/how are `this.pause` and `this.resume` defined?

Comment: `this.pause` and `this.resume`  are defined insid the class TimerElement. You can see the method pause down to render method.

Comment: I guess you should bind `this.pause` before pass it. Try `Template.timerElementOperation(this.pause.bind(this), 'pause')`.

Comment: And what is `Template`? How you can call `Template.timerElementOperation`? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!  It's work with `Templale.timerElementOperation(this.pause.bind(this),'pause')`. 

I was setting the bind when  the context had already changed.

Template is is a import from the file timer-template.js.  `import * as Template from '../templates/timer-template.js';`

Comment: Could you please add the entire example? I need more context to answer your question. You can generally solve issues like this without explicitly rebinding methods to `this`.

Answer (score 0):

How should the template in `Template.timerElementOperation` know what `this` should be? It's an isolated function.

There's two ways about this - the first is to explicitly bind `this`: replace `this.pause` with `this.pause.bind(this)`. This will work, but honestly makes for fairly idiosyncratic code.

The common practice is to use the fact that any `@event` binding in Lit will have `this` bound for you to the class it's in, so:

```
class TimerElement 
    extends LitElement{
    ...

    renderTimerElementOperation(operation){
        return html`<button @click=${this[operation]}>${operation}</button>`;
    }

    render(){
        let partialTemplate;
        if( this.isPausable(this.running, this.finished) && this.time > 0 ){
            partialTemplate = this.timerElementOperation('pause');
        } else if(!this.running && this.time > 0){
            partialTemplate = this.timerElementOperation('resume');
        }

        return html`... ${partialTemplate} ...`
    }
}
```

This is a lot simpler, and you generally want to keep the templates with or in the associated elements, rather than imported. If you want something re-usuable create *another* LitElement to reuse that, rather than importing functions that render templates in isolation.